# Find the date that sequencing was performed

Tags: rna-seq, ngs, public-databases

**Background** I've obtained RNAseq datasets from ENCODE and I'm looking to identify external variables contributing to sequence variance among these samples.

**External variables** For example, clustering effects on the date the sequencing was performed.

**Questions** How do I find out the precise date which each sample went through the sequencing machine?

---

ENCODE databases are [here on NCBI](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/geo/encode/)
The [ENCODE website is here](https://www.encodeproject.org)

Comment: What kind of data do you have? Do you have the count table or the original fastq files? Where did you get this files from (If you got it from someone could you ask him/her) ?

Comment: I downloaded them directly from the ENCODE website. I thought to ask here before e-mailing.

Comment: And why do you need the date? It is for batch finding? I don't know the metadata for the project but usually there documentation about how is this encoded

Comment: @Llopis: Yes, I'm looking to correct for variance associated with dates. Maybe I'm stretching it, but I'm really interested in parsing through the noise of the different datasets at all factor levels

Comment: Will you want to know which person did each part of the process? Or in which center, machine and lane it was done? I agree that this should be an objective, but I think it is unreasonable to ask this of this big projects, any way you can ask them. But I see there is a "Date released" filter value, so you can use that as a proxy

Comment: Yes, I agree-- for some parts it may be overkill. Date released corresponds to when the consortium released the data to the public. In fact, the sequencing lane and machines are in fact available in the library metadata! I thought maybe there is a way to get date information from a fastq file... I've read that dates are fingerprinted onto microarrays.